# Name of a Chinese sweet

Tags: dessert, chinese-cuisine, food-identification

In the past I have bought this Chinese sweet which name I cannot recall.

It is shaped in little cubes of some sort of trasparent dark jelly (not sure if it is actually gelatine, but it has a gelatinous consistency) containing peanuts and covered with slightly roasted white sesame seeds.

Does anyone know their name and can possibly tell me how to make them?

Comment: Are you talking about "zi mah goh", sesame jello?  http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_17GWj2EcDoI/TJi8lp71p1I/AAAAAAAAAwQ/U7DkRI0Fwm0/s1600/P9210171.JPG (no sesame seeds in this picture)

Answer (score 3):

You may be thinking of *Fah Sung Thong*. You can find a recipe for it [here](http://en.petitchef.com/recipes/chinese-peanut-candyfah-sung-thong-fid-303308).

Comment: It looks similar, but with way less peanuts. The base is pretty much all jelly (it vaguely resembles to a lokum).

Comment: Definitely jelly? It's soft?

Comment: Yes it is soft. I has jelly-like consistency, but I don't know whether it is actually made with gelatin.